# MongoDB Query array based on value of another field

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I need to be able to find any conditions inside an array of a document in my collection based on the value of another field.
My document:

```
{
    "totalSteps": 3,
    "currentStep": 2,
    "status": "submitted",
    "completed": false,
    "completedDate": null,
    "orderBody": [
        {
            "status": "complete",
            "stepStarted": 1617207419303,
            "stepEnded": "",
            "executionOutput": ""
        },
        {
            "status": "incomplete",
            "stepStarted": 1617211111113,
            "stepEnded": "",
            "executionOutput": ""
        },
        {
            "status": "incomplete",
            "stepStarted": 1617207419303,
            "stepEnded": "",
            "executionOutput": ""
        }
    ],

}
```

My query:

```
           ...find($and: [
            { orderBody: {$elemMatch: { "stepStarted" : { $lte: currentTime }, status : "incomplete"}}},
            {status: { $ne: "failed"}}
          ])
```

My Issue:
I need the document returned only if the value of (currentStep - 1) is the same as the matched array. Right now the query will return the document because the conditions of orderBody[2] are fulfilled. Notice the stepStarted of orderBody[2] is < orderBody[1]. currentTime is a variable passed from server in another section of code.

I've tried:

```
           $and: [
            { currentStep:{ {$indexOfArray: {orderBody: {$elemMatch: { "stepStarted" : { $lte: currentTime }, status : "incomplete"}}} - 1}},
            {status: { $ne: "failed"}}
          ]

           $and: [
            { currentStep: { $eq: {$indexOfArray: {orderBody: {$elemMatch: { "stepStarted" : { $lte: currentTime }, status : "incomplete"}}}},
            {status: { $ne: "failed"}}
          ]},

          { $and: [
            {orderBody[currentStep - 1]: {$elemMatch: { "stepStarted" : { $lte: currentTime }, status : "incomplete"}}},
            {status: { $ne: "failed"}}
          ]},
```

Any assistance on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Demo - https://mongoplayground.net/p/d2ew5peV-z-

Use [$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) to extract exact array element pipeline you want from orderBody. Using [$arrayElemAt](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/).

[$subtract](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/subtract/) `currentStep` value 1 to get the correct index ([$toInt](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toInt/))

After that run your [$match](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) query on the document.

```
db.collection.aggregate({
  $project: {
    orderBody: {
      "$arrayElemAt": [ "$orderBody", { $subtract: [ { $toInt: "$currentStep" }, 1 ] } ]
    }
  }
},
{
  $match: {
    "orderBody.stepStarted": { $gte: NumberLong(1217207419302) },
    "orderBody.status": "incomplete"
  }
})
```

Note- add details you want to project in `$project` pipeline.

---

### Update

Demo - https://mongoplayground.net/p/E8Wo_YfFltq

Use [$addFields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/)

```
db.collection.aggregate({
  $addFields: {
    currentOrderBody: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$orderBody", { $subtract: [ {  $toInt: "$currentStep" }, 1 ] } ] }
  }
},
{
  $match: {
    "currentOrderBody.stepStarted": { $gte: NumberLong(1217207419302) },
    "currentOrderBody.status": "incomplete"
  }
})
```